# Build issue using code::blocks, intel c++compler

Tags: codeblocks

I am getting the following warning when I use Code::Block / Intel C++ Compiler:
"myLib.a is an archive, but has no symbols (this can happen if ar is used where xiar is needed)"
This is followed by Linker errors for missing symbols.
The project builds fine in gcc compiler.
How do I have code blocks run xiar instead of ar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I have code blocks run xiar instead of ar?

- In the Code::Blocks IDE navigate **Settings** -> **Compiler**
- Set **Selected Compiler** = Intel C++ (whatever you have called it)
- Tab to **Toolchain executables** -> **Program files**
- In the edit box **Linker for static libs** change `ar` to `xiar` (or
  possibly `path/to/xiar`, if the Intel tools aren't in your `PATH`)